# Open source code to upload test results into HP QC/ALM?

Tags: quality-center

Is there some open source code, available to upload test results into HP QC via their api, or will I need to write something myself?

Ideally via REST, so it can be done from non-windows machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about open source code. But I tried something similar using QC OTA API with Excel. But to use this, your machine need to have QC Client installed and then take a reference to QC Object using OTA in Excel VBA Project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a QC plug-in available to do this job without much fuss. Please [read section-3 here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fupdate.external.hp.com%2Fqualitycenter%2Fqc100%2Fmsoffice%2Fmsexcel%2FQCMSExcelAddin.pdf&ei=QZKLUeToLMusrAfeyIDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNHfU-U_PpZCNRkSRze3g2CrrX1jFA&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bmk&cad=rja) to know more. I hope this answers your question. This is certainly not open source though ;)

Comment: As far as I am aware the add in can upload test cases, not results.

Comment: I did not try this but I think if your excel sheet has got a `result` column then you just map it to the QC field and upload.